# how to make bash/shell script that make a 'shortcut' for a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Write a shell script 'shortcut' that does the following: You
will need to use temporary files.

Associates the tag 'myls' with the command 'ls -lart'

```
dirk@linux /home/dirk> ./shortcut -a myls ls -lart
```

runs "ls -lart"

```
   dirk@linux /home/dirk> ./shortcut myls
```

delete myls

```
dirk@linux /home/dirk> ./shortcut -d myls
OK, shortcut 'myls' deleted.
```

show content of myls

```
dirk@linux /home/dirk> ./shortcut -l myls
```

Shortcut 'myls' = ls -lart

```
dirk@linux /home/dirk>
```

You will need to create an shortcuts associations file.

Call it ".shortcuts" in the current working directory.

I would like to put this into case/if elif statement, where I can put the 'command ls -lart' into 'myls', every i exec., ./shortcut -a myls ls -lart, the command 'ls -lart', will be inputted to 'myls', and when i run the 'myls' like, './shorcut myls', it will exec., the command on the 'myls'.. thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like an assignment. Have you given it a shot yourself? Do you have a specific question about any part of it that we can help with?

Comment: i'm putting it in case & if else statement.. i'm new in bash, and i'm doing a self study.. my problem is, when i put the command on 'myls', it will not execute the command in 'myls' file, is there anyway i can make it executable or other method?? thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in what you have so far, and what the output is when you run what you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same using `alias` command. See `alias` man page for details

1) To associate:

```
alias myls='ls -lart'
```

2) You can use the command as `myls`. U can see existing aliases with `alias -p`. You can list `myls` as `alias -p | grep myls`

3) To delete `myls`:

```
unalias myls
```

Comment: w0w, these saves me alot.. such a help! thanks @A.M.D.

Comment: hi @A.M.D. is there anyway i can achieve it? without using alias? thanks